# Checking user availability

Tags: php, version

I have upgraded from php5.2 to php5.3. Before this my code was working fine. After up gradation I am getting the error " the email is already in use...." though the email is not exist in the database. Please help.

```
<?php
$request = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['username']));

$query = "SELECT username FROM advt WHERE username = '$username';";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$valid = 'true';

if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)
    $valid= '"The email is already in use, please choose another"';
{
    echo $valid;
}
?>
```

Comment: FYI, mysql functions are deprecated, you should use mysqli or PDO

Comment: Don't use mysql_*, use mysqli_* or PDO. Anyway, you have an extra semicolon in your query

Comment: That means I have to use mysqli instead of mysql?

Comment: Yes, check the documentation: mysql_* is deprecated and you CAN'T use it anymore in php 5.3, as far as I know. use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: ``mysql`` functions are deprecated in PHP ``5.5.0`` so using ``mysqli`` functions is true but don't help on this question. You should use the syntax ``if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){ // dublicate } else { //ok }``

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation in PDO. It might not be working because mysql functions are deprecated in php 5.5. replace `dbname=test` to your database name, and create a `$user` and `$pass` variable to access it with correct permission

```
$username = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['username']));
try {
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'password';

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM advt WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1;"); //Limit this to one result
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username); // bind the parameters to prevent sql injection
    $stmt->execute();

    $valid = 'true';
    //returns an array of results
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //If the array is empty, no results have been returned
    if (count($result) != 0) {
        $valid = '"The email is already in use, please choose another"';
    }

    $dbh = null;
    echo $valid;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

$query = "SELECT username FROM advt WHERE username =
'{$username}';";